# Need alternative to POST data using navigateToURL that works with Pepper Flash plugin

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, google-chrome

As most people know, Google messed several flash applications after starting using Pepper Flash plugin in Chrome.

I'm getting the same problem, but it can't be solved with external interface call, as I need to post data using POST, to a php file.

My application basicaly takes a screenshot, and post to a php file. Worked fine before, but now with Pepper Flash, nothing happens.

This is the piece of code that POSTs the data.

```
jpgURLRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
jpgURLRequest.data = jpgStream;
navigateToURL(URL_TO_THE_PHP_FILE, "_self");
```

Is there a workaround for this? My website that uses this application have thousands visitors daily, and most users woudn't know how to disable pepper flash.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To upload image, you will need `URLLoader`, image encoding algorithm, and some contract(names of variables in POST's body, encoding algorithm, etc) with you server-side

```
var urlRequest : URLRequest = new URLRequest();
var urlLoader : URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var urlVars : URLVariables = new URLVariables();

//Take from the image bytes, for example with JPEGEncoder
//Endoce ByteArray for example with Base64
//If image is big, you can split on several parts
urlVars.image = Base64.encode(imageData);

urlRequest.url = $snapshotUploadURL;
urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
urlRequest.data = urlVars;

// create the image loader & send the image to the server;
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
```

[BloodyCrypto is very helpful library](http://www.blooddy.by/ru/crypto/) for this task.

Comment: This isn't working for me.  I see the complete function trigger, but nothing is loaded.  I am attempting to send image data to my .php to save locally from a .swf

Comment: You doing something wrong. Because It's a part of working solution from commercial project.

Comment: I've discovered that I needed to change the header. Needs to be a "Simple Header".  Currently working on decoding my byte array from my new text/plain header and generating the image out of it now :)